# Dynamic SQL Stored Proc to Linq to SQL

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, reflection, dynamic

I have a stored procedure that returns a selection from a table. The table is selected dynamically. The procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[GetRecordsInViewPort]
    @DatabaseName VarChar(100),
    @TableName VarChar(100),
AS
  Declare @SQL VarChar(1000)

  SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' 
  SELECT @SQL = @SQL + + @DatabaseName + '.dbo.' + @TableName

  EXEC(@SQL)
```

It works fine in SQL when I execute it. How do I go about using this procedure from Linq-to-SQL? When I try to execute it, I just get 0 back. The return type property on the stored procedure in the Linq-to-SQL designer is set to `(None)` and cannot be modified.

Is it possible to map the stored procedure result on the fly, then get a `List<<r>dynamic>` back?

In a nutshell, I think I'm looking to accept the results of a stored procedure as a dynamic List, whose properties I can access at runtime through reflection. Any ideas?

Also, if this is easier to do in Linq-To-Entities, I am open to anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = dataContext.ExecuteQuery<Customer>(
  @"EXEC GetRecordsInViewPort {0},{1}", "databaseName", "Customer");

List<Customer> result = customers.ToList();
```

---

```
<Soapbox>
```

> I'm looking to accept the results of a stored proc as a dynamic List, whose properties I can access at runtime

The whole point of LinqToSql is to construct compiler checked queries and get compiler checked results.  If you don't want to do those things, you shouldn't use this ORM.

You could use [SqlConnection.ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to plainly fetch data.

```
</Soapbox>
```

Comment: The stored procedure is selecting which type of result will be returned. I will not know that a set of Customers is returned at compile-time. It could be Dogs, it could be Airplanes, so I do not think this will work. I get where you are coming from with the soapbox, and I would normally never use dynamic Linq or SQL if I can help it, but the specifics of this case do seem to require it. I could care less if it uses an ORM or not, I just need a way to read the data into a .Net List.